# "python-social-auth" or "django-social-auth"

Tags: django, social-networking, python-social-auth

I am new in social networks.
I have a project on  django (v1.10.1).
I'm trying to add authorization.

What better to use "python-social-auth" or "django-social-auth"?

Comment: + Why it's better?

Comment: If you had actually researched your problem yourself you'd find that django-social-auth is "DEPRECATED IN FAVOR OF python-social-auth. "

Comment: Thank you. You absolutely right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django-social-auth has a [very clear warning](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth#readme) that it is deprecated in favour of python-social-auth.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen it, but there were problems with the connection.
I hesitated and decided to check :)

Answer (score 1):

Python-social-auth  is derived from django-social-auth with the idea of generalizing the process to suit the different frameworks around.
So the newest version is "python-social-auth". And it is split in smaller components that focus on providing a simpler functionality.
so for django u can use "social-auth-app-django".
More details of this can get from this link.
http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html